# Unable to use NERDCommenter with vundle

Tags: vim, vundle, nerdcommenter

I am using vim `The-NERD-Commenter` plugin along with `vundle`. But I am not able to get the plugin to work.

I have my leader ley mapped to `,`. When I run the `:scriptnames` command I see that `~\vimfiles\bundle\The-NERD-Commenter\plugin\NERD_commenter.vim` is listed in the output. I am also able to bring up help for `NERDCommenter` using `:help NERDCommenter` command which tells me that the plugin is installed correctly. But when I try to toggle a comment using `<leader>c<space>` which translates in my case to `,c` it invokes the change command instead.

I have my `.vimrc` file here https://gist.github.com/bAmrish/be1aac3aeb087925a3e5

Update:

It looks like if I remove the leader key mapping from my `.vimrc` file then the plugin starts working with the default leader key `\`.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
Amrish

Comment: Are you installing the plugin twice? Lines 15 & 29?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installing the plugin twice (lines 15, 29):

```
Plugin 'The-NERD-Commenter'
Plugin 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git'
```

From scanning the README, the scrooloose version doesn't seem to support the c shortcut, so it may be doing some blocking. Reread the documentations and choose one of the two. Post back if your problem isn't solved by one of those two actions.

UPDATE:
Okay, digging deeper. The plugin's .vim code runs the following line:

```
let leader = exists('g:mapleader') ? g:mapleader : '\'
```

In your vim try running

```
:echo exists('g:mapleader')
:echo 'g:mapleader'
```

If the mapleader exists and spits back , as expected, then we need to look for unexpected/buggy code in the plugin. If it doesn't exist or isn't , as you expect, then we know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: i removed and uninstalled the scrooloose version still the problem remains. I am able to get the plugin to work with the default leader key `\` but not with my custom mapped leader key `,`.